# In Prestashop: How can I have a catalog with different prices for the same product depending on the country from where it is viewed?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

Is there a module to be able to set different prices for the same product depending on the country from which they are ordered?

It is that our idea is that the base price of the product will vary before taxes depending on the country from where they saw it, but the modules that exist are only to convert to other currencies.

Comment: you can override function getPrice in Product.php class

Answer (score 0):

You can use the in-built specific price function and
set up prices for country without any third party module.

You would also enable Geolocation so a visitor country can be detected by his IP before he actually enter a shipping address and he can have the correct price shown.

Comment: Oh, it's just what I needed. Thank you very much for the reply! It has been very useful to me.